# Sizeof rounds to the alignment, but the compiler still places objects in the remaining bytes

Tags: c++, struct, c++17, memory-alignment

Considering the code and its output below

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class alignas(8) Something {
    std::uint8_t integer{};
};

int main() {
    auto something = Something{};
    auto character = std::uint8_t{};

    cout << sizeof(something) << endl;
    cout << reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&something) << endl;
    cout << reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&character) << endl;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/m6D0PYWyrGlfjYJP.  Output from a single run

```
8
140729604143976
140729604143975
```

If I have a struct that is aligned to 8 bytes, calling `sizeof` on it rounds the size of the struct to the nearest multiple of its alignment. But the compiler is still able to place objects in that hypothetical space left by the rounded up size.

In what cases is this allowed? Is it always allowed? Why does `sizeof` round the size up here if it's not respected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its placed `something` at `140729604143976` which is `0x7FFE2A107B68` 
Its placed `character` at `140729604143975` which is `0x7FFE2A107B67`

Note that `character` has been placed at the byte *before* `something` in memory and is therefore valid. `something` runs from `0x7FFE2A107B68` to `0x7FFE2A107B70` and doesn't overlap with `character` at all.